# How to pass parameters in lambda by cloud custodian?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloudcustodian

I've one scenario like I want to invoke one lambda function by cloud custodian and want to pass newly created bucket name to that lambda function. is there any way to pass parameters to the lambda function from the custodian event? Thanks
-- below is my cloud custodian policy:-

```
policies:

name: lambda-s3-configure-standards-real-time
resource: aws.lambda
description: |
This policy is triggered when a new S3 bucket is created and it will invoke another lambda.
mode:
type: cloudtrail
events:
- CreateBucket
role: some-role
timeout: 200
actions:
- type: invoke-lambda
function: Lambda-function-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the lambda function's event dictionary that is passed as the payload to your invoked lambda function? I believe the bucket name should already be present as part of the payload readily.
As an example, when the bucket is created via console your payload should contain the Bucket Name at `$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName`